# if the member of any group has only the execute permission will the be able to enter into the directory belongs to that group?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, group

```
# mkdir -p /test/music # created this dir as a root
# chmod g=x,o= /test   # rwx--x---
# gpasswd -a x1 root   # adding x1 user into the root group

# su - x1              # login as x1
$ cd /test
         permission denied
```

`x1` belong to the root group and the group has the execute permission it means `x1` should be able to enter into the `/test` directory, but why permission denied?

Comment: but i'm able to change dir to `/test` as `x1`

Comment: [x1@server27 test]$

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -ld /test`. And of `id` as the `x1` user.

Comment: Being granted execute on a directory allows you to enter the directory, but not list the contents of the directory. It is unclear from the combination of your question and comments (please edit & expand you question with your comments), but I think you are able to `cd /test` successfully (i.e. it becomes your new working directory), but you also see 'permission denied' as you do. Do you have anything setup in your profile that looks at the contents of a each new working directory as you move through the filesystem?  (Perhaps to set a custom PS)